# Accessing the value of every key of a JSON formatted list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following list, which I have queried with the help of `json_query` from cisco controller.

```
"aci_access_port_list": [
            [
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON KASTOM"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-17"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "ASDF NOMON K"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-16"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON K9876"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-15"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "LAN5002 TC "
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-46"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "LAN5002 TC "
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-47"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON LAN5001 TC "
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-45"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "LAN5001 TC "
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-48"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON No Cabling - TEST-4-AUTOMATION"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-30"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON No Cabling - TEST-6-AUTOMATION"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-31"
                }
            ]
        ]
```

I want to check every `description`  key and if it has "*NOMON K*" written save it into a new list. For this I wrote the following:

```
- set_fact:
    clean_list: [\n]
- name: getting the clean list of ports and descr.
  set_fact:
    clean_list: "{{clean_list }} \n {{item.0.port_name}} - {{item.1}}"
  loop: "{{ aci_access_port_list[0]|subelements('description') }}"
  when: item.1 is search ("NOMON K")

- debug:
    msg: "{{ clean_list }}"
```

and this returns:

```
ok: [acitst-apic.net.dsh.at] => {
    "msg": "[u'\\\\n'] \n E1-17 - NOMON KASTOM \n E1-16 - ASDF NOMON K \n E1-15 - NOMON K9876"
}
```

What I want to have is same formatting as  `aci_access_port_lists` but I couldn't figure it out. It should look like:

```
"clean_list":[
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON KASTOM"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-17"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "ASDF NOMON K"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-16"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": [
                        "NOMON K9876"
                    ], 
                    "port_name": "E1-15"
                }
             ]
```

I assume there is a better way but I couldn't find it and if somebody can help me I will be glad. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easilly feasible using the `selectattr` filter and the `contains` test, targeting the first element of the `description` list since it always has a single element. Of course, this approach will break if you have several elements in that list.

```yaml
    - name: Show me a clean list
      vars:                                                                                                  
        clean_list: >-
          {{
            aci_access_port_list.0 |
            selectattr('description.0', 'contains', 'NOMON K') |
            list
          }}
      debug:
        var: clean_list
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you @Zeitounator, that helped a lot. Can you explain what is the exact function of `>-`? 
I have tried to write `clean_list` into a file, but it didn't work than I used your solution as follows:
`- set_fact:
    test_list: " {{aci_access_port_list.0 | selectattr('description.0', 'contains', 'NOMON K') | list | to_nice_json}} "`

Comment: `>-` is a yaml block scalar indicator. See https://yaml-multiline.info/. I used it here mainly for readability (splitting the expression on multiple lines)

Comment: Regarding writing to a file... Instead of `set_fact` use `copy` and put your expression in the `content` attribute.

Comment: because of a bug `copy` doesn't work thus I'm using the following:
`local_action: shell echo "{{ clean_list | to_nice_json }}" > "{{ path_to_ports }}{{ leaf_profile }}"`

Comment: I can assure you at 200% that it works even when delegating to localhost. Don't use local_action. delegate_to: localhost instead. Much easier to read and to write

Comment: Hi again, 
I wanted to just show you too which error that I'm getting. Maybe you have an idea.
This is what I'm trying to do:
`copy:
    content: "{{ free_port_list | to_nice_json }}"
    dest: "{{ path_to_free_ports }}{{ leaf_name }}"
  delegate_to: localhost`
and this is what I'm getting:
`"msg": "Failed to replace file: /../FREE_PORTS/ACITST-LEAF2: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/.../FREE_PORTS/.ansible_tmp2O9u5OACITST-LEAF2'"`

Comment: Do not spread information needer to answer your question over comments. Edit your question instead or ask an other question. Regarding your error message `operation not permitted` seems quite obvious and does not look like any ansible bug to me. Note: having an absolute path to a file starting with `/..` looks like a chair to keyboard interface problem IMO...